# Generating error - missing controller after refactoring plugin in cakephp 3.x

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I had created a plugin named **PedidaAdmin**. After creating I refactored the plugin name as **PediaBackOffice** . After refactoring when I am going to browse action of controller of PediaBackOffice pluing, then I am getting error like "missing controller" .

Comment: with all the extensive info given in this question I can only say that your refactoring went wrong and you should fix it

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 step to load plugin when replace plugin name:

1. First of all you have to replace plugin name from root/config/bootstrap.php file 
   such as

Plugin::load('PediaBackOffice', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);

2. In the cakephp 3.x, this will not auto load this plugin, for auto loading plugin, you to change at   "autoload" ={} in the root/plugins/plugin_name/composer.js
3. Finally you have to replace plugin name in the root/vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php